# Finding Prime Numbers Java

Tags: java

I was trying to write some code that took in a maximum number and that gave me all the prime numbers between 2 and the max number. It is almost working but I am having the problem that prints all the prime numbers but it also prints the result of the same prime number being multiplied. For example it will print 2,3,4,5,7,9 which are all the prime numbers between 0 and 10 but it also prints extra numbers which are 2 * 2, 3*3 and so on. Please guide me in the right direction so that I can finish this program.

```
public class PrimeNumbers 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int max = 400;

        //Runs through all the numbers between 2 and max, checks if
        //the number is prime and prints it
        for( int num = 2; num < max; ++num )
        {
            if( isPrimeNumber( num ) )
            {
                System.out.println( num );
            }
        }
    }

    //method to find all prime numbers
    public static boolean isPrimeNumber( int number )
    {
        for( int mod = 2; mod < Math.sqrt( number ); ++mod )
        {
            if( number % mod == 0 )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 4 is not prime, 9 is not prime...

Comment: Even if the compiler will probably inline the `Math.sqrt` call, I would recommend you to do it yourself.

Comment: I know this, this is why I said that it prints all the prime numbers plus some extra numbers that are not prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your end condition is wrong, you need to go all the way up to `sqrt(num)`:

```
for (int mod = 2; mod <= Math.sqrt(number); ++mod)
```

Comment: This question is asking about why the "prime" numbers are being printed after (2*2, etc) your answer does not address this

Comment: It does address it, the OP's method is only wrong for square numbers, that's why he gets `true` for 4 and 9.

Comment: Yeah this definitely solves my problem, still not sure why but it works fine now

Comment: @ed1234567: You can see why for the examples `4` and `9`. Here `Math.sqrt(number)` will be `2` and `3`, so the loop will end at `1` and `2`, so the only divider will never be found.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. I definitely understand why it wasn't working before.

Answer (score 0):

For future users i am posting this program for primes. You just give the max number you want your primes to return.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 2;
        int y = 2;
        int i = 0;
        int m = 0;
        int t = 1;
        int j = 2;
        int cal = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter for how many numbers \nyou wanna check if their prime");

        m = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            while (j <= x) {
                t = x % y;

                if (t == 0) {
                    cal = cal + 1;
                }

                y++;
                j++;
            }

            if (cal == 1) {
                System.out.println("Prime number: " + x);
            }

            cal = 0;
            x++;
            y = 2;
            j = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this implementation is inefficient in terms of time complexity. A sieve approach is much faster.